# pkcs12 client cert file for postgres jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, jdbc

I'm trying to use client cert in a pkcs12 file for postgres JDBC auth, but it's not working for me.  I've tried a variety of versions of the driver >= 42.2.9.  Some of them provide different stack traces, but I think they boil down to the same thing.

Per [the doc](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/ssl/)

> As of version 42.2.9 PKCS-12 is also supported. In this archive format the client key and the client certificate are in one file, which needs to be set with the sslkey parameter. For the PKCS-12 format to be recognized, the file extension must be “.p12” (supported since 42.2.9) or “.pfx” (since 42.2.16). (In this case the sslcert parameter is ignored.)

I even extracted the pems from the pkcs12 file (there's a chain of certs up to and including the CA, as well as the key for the leaf cert), created a chain cert pem file, and a pkcs8 file for the key, and *that* works fine.  I then created a new p12 file from the pem & pkcs8 files, and that doesn't work either.

I've also created a properties file, and passed that into the `getConnection`, and I get the same error.

The code below (edited for brevity) yields the output below that.

My gut tells me that there's some kind of encoding issue, but I can't find doc on what pkcs12 encodings are accepted by the postgres driver (I also created a p12 file using "-descert", same result).  Another idea is that I may need some jar on the classpath at runtime, but I also can't find doc on that.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

```
    log.info("the all-args-in-the-uri uri is {}", uri);
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(uri)) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("problem with query-args based appoach", e);
    }
```

```
13:59:36.411 [main] INFO  com.company_name.app_name.App - the all-args-in-the-uri uri is jdbc:postgresql://hostname.net:5432/db_name?sslmode=verify-ca&sslpassword=company_name&sslkey=/Users/user_name/git/certDbApp/local/nss1/2023-02-14/ssl_cert.p12&sslcert=/Users/user_name/git/certDbApp/local/nss1/2023-02-14/ssl_cert.p12&ssl=true&user=app_name-prod_readonly&sslrootcert=/Users/user_name/git/certDbApp/local/nss1/2023-02-14/canonical_ca_roots.pem
13:59:37.568 [main] ERROR com.company_name.app_name.App - problem with query-args based appoach
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not find a java cryptographic algorithm: X.509 CertificateFactory not available.
    at org.postgresql.ssl.PKCS12KeyManager.getCertificateChain(PKCS12KeyManager.java:116) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.ssl.PKCS12KeyManager.chooseClientAlias(PKCS12KeyManager.java:77) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractKeyManagerWrapper.chooseClientAlias(SSLContextImpl.java:1744) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createClientPossession(X509Authentication.java:231) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:206) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.choosePossession(CertificateMessage.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1102) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:958) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.onConsumeFinished(Finished.java:1011) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.consume(Finished.java:874) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:40) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:135) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677) ~[java.sql:na]
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251) ~[java.sql:na]
    at com.company_name.app_name.App.testUriBased(App.java:265) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.company_name.app_name.App.main(App.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.postgresql.ssl.PKCS12KeyManager.getCertificateChain(PKCS12KeyManager.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar:42.2.9]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
13:59:37.568 [main] INFO  com.company_name.app_name.App -
```

Comment: It turns out that if I add an alias of "user" (not the name of the user.  Literally "user") to the cert in the pkcs12 file, it works.  That can _not_ be the intended solution.

Comment: What does 'adding an alias of "user"' look like, in terms of openssl commands.  Or whatever tool is being used.

Comment: `openssl pkcs12 -export -out ssl_cert_with_user_username.p12 -in cert.pem -name user -inkey cert.key -passout pass:changeit`

yields

`openssl pkcs12 -info -in local/nss1/2023-02-14/ssl_cert_with_user_username.p12 | grep friendly`
    friendlyName: user

Comment: I was also having a problem connecting, different exception `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate`. Adding `-name user` to `openssl pkcs12 -export` seems to solve the issue. To be fair, docs [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/) actually mention this. For some reason though I need to provide both `sslcert` and `sslkey`, where sslkey is the PKCS 12 file.